# Aptitude install wants to remove many libs

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, aptitude, udisks

After execution of command `sudo aptitude install udisks` I got following message:

```
ggg@gmLatitude:~$ sudo aptitude install udisks
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cryptsetup-bin{a} libcryptsetup4{a} libdevmapper-event1.02.1{a} liblvm2app2.2{a} udisks 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gcc-4.8-base:i386{u} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{u} libasound2:i386{u} libatk1.0-0:i386{u} libavahi-client3:i386{u} libavahi-common-data:i386{u} 
  libavahi-common3:i386{u} libcairo2:i386{u} libcups2:i386{u} libcurl3:i386{u} libdatrie1:i386{u} libdbus-glib-1-2:i386{u} libdbusmenu-glib4:i386{u} 
  libdbusmenu-gtk4:i386{u} libexpat1:i386{u} libffi6:i386{u} libfontconfig1:i386{u} libfreetype6:i386{u} libgconf-2-4:i386{u} libgcrypt11:i386{u} 
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386{u} libglib2.0-0:i386{u} libgnutls26:i386{u} libgpg-error0:i386{u} libgraphite2-3:i386{u} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{u} 
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{u} libgtk2.0-0:i386{u} libharfbuzz0b:i386{u} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{u} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{u} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{u} 
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{u} libidn11:i386{u} libjasper1:i386{u} libjbig0:i386{u} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{u} libjpeg8:i386{u} libk5crypto3:i386{u} libkeyutils1:i386{u} 
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{u} libkrb5-3:i386{u} libkrb5support0:i386{u} libldap-2.4-2:i386{u} libnspr4:i386{u} libnss3:i386{u} libp11-kit0:i386{u} 
  libpango-1.0-0:i386{u} libpango1.0-0:i386{u} libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386{u} libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386{u} libpangox-1.0-0:i386{u} libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386{u} 
  libpixman-1-0:i386{u} libroken18-heimdal:i386{u} librtmp0:i386{u} libsasl2-2:i386{u} libsasl2-modules:i386{u} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{u} libsqlite3-0:i386{u} 
  libssl1.0.0:i386{u} libstdc++6:i386{u} libtasn1-6:i386{u} libthai0:i386{u} libtiff5:i386{u} libwind0-heimdal:i386{u} libx11-6:i386{u} libxau6:i386{u} 
  libxcb-render0:i386{u} libxcb-shm0:i386{u} libxcb1:i386{u} libxcomposite1:i386{u} libxcursor1:i386{u} libxdamage1:i386{u} libxdmcp6:i386{u} libxext6:i386{u} 
  libxfixes3:i386{u} libxft2:i386{u} libxi6:i386{u} libxinerama1:i386{u} libxrandr2:i386{u} libxrender1:i386{u} libxss1:i386{u} libxtst6:i386{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 84 to remove and 265 not upgraded.
Need to get 583 kB of archives. After unpacking 42.0 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
```

Why this installation is planning to remove so many libraries? Is it not dangerous for the system?

Comment: some updates replace the old packages. this is common for updates of the linux kernel. are your repositories up to date?